# Running php via a unix script

Tags: php, linux, shell

I have the above shell script .

```
#!/bin/bash

# a shell script that keeps looping until an exit code is given

nice php -q -f ./data.php -- $@
ERR=$?

exec $0 $@
```

I have a few doubts

1. What is `$0` and what is `$@`
2. what is `ERR=$?`
3. what does  `-- $@` in 5th line do
4. I wanted to know if can i pass data.php as a parameter. so that i have only i shell script for all kind of execution . Say, i want to run "sh ss.sh data1.php" then this should run data1.php, if run "ss ss.sh data2.php" it should run data2.php –

Comment: $@ the arguments $0 the first argument ERR is the return value from the execution

Comment: [Doubts?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=444996)

Comment: -- $@ passes all the arguments to php   http://linux.die.net/man/1/php

Comment: now I understand your 4th question .. try something like "`php $1 -- $@``

Comment: cant seem to be able to get those quotations right.. arrgh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `$0` is the name of the executable (the script in your case, eg: if your script is called `start_me` then `$0` is `start_me`)

2) `ERR=$?` gets the return code of `nice php -q -f ./data.php -- $@`

3) `-- $@` does two things, first of all it tell the `php` command that all following parameter shall be passed to `data.php` and `$@` passes all given parameter to the script to `./data.php` (eg. `./your_script_name foo bar` will translate to `nice php -q -f ./data.php -- foo bar`)

4) short answer yes, but you have to change the script to

```
 YOUR_FILE=$1
 shift #this removes the first argument from $@
 nice php -q -f ./$YOUR_FILE -- $@
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$0
```

is the name of the script.

```
$@
```

are the arguments given to the script

```
ERR=$?
```

catches the status code of the previous command

```
php_command="php -q -f $1"
shift
nice $php_command -- $@
```

You take the first parameter for the f-flag, then you shift it off the parameter list and pass the rest after the double dashes.

Comment: i want to run "sh ss.sh data.php" . this run run data.php  i if run "ss ss.sh data2.php" it should run data2.php

Comment: will the last line holds true in your case i.e exec $0 $@

Comment: You should not call the exec-function because it will execute your program a second time. This could cause a recursive loop.